# How to compute this cohomology group algebraically

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I want to compute the group: 
$H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2},\mathbb{Z}_{n})$ 
view in terms of  normalized cochains, so as quotient of

$$ker\partial^{3}=\{f\mid f(x_{1},x_{2})-f(x_{1}+x_{2},x_{3})+f(x_{1},x_{2}+x_{3})-f(x_{1},x_{2})x_{3}=[0]_{n}\}$$

on

$$Im\partial^{2}=\{f\mid f(x_{1},x_{2})=g(x_{1})-g(x_{1}+x_{2})+g(x_{1})x_{2}\}$$
for a 1-cocycle $g$.

The main problem is how $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$: we know that this means to fix a group homomomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{2}\longrightarrow Aut\mathbb{Z}_{n}$. So for a fixed homomorphism, what can we say about $H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2},\mathbb{Z}_{n})$? And how many actions can we fix?

By $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ I mean the cyclic group and not a $p$-adic structure.

Comment: what is $\mathbb Z_n$ for you? do you actually mean $\mathbb Z_n$ or $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$?

Comment: The more practical way to compute the cohomology of cyclic groups (if you indeed mean that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is the cyclic group, which seems likely) is not by using usual cochains. You should probably rather use the fact that $H^2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},A)$ is isomorphic to the fixed points in $A$ modulo the norms.